# What kind of IO error is thrown when Java tries to recursively walk a directory structure with a circular symbolic link?

Tags: java, io, symlink, java-6

Consider this standard directory traversal code:

```
static void walk(File f) throws IOException{
    System.out.println(f.getPath());

    if(f.isFile()) return;  // leaf

    File[] subs = f.listFiles(); // If it aint a file, it's a directory. Right? 

    if(subs == null) return; // returns null at some point

    for(File subDir : subs){
        walk(subDir.getAbsoluteFile()); 
    }
}
```

If I execute it on the following directory structure: `c:\ -> Folder1 -> Folder2 (=a symbolic link to c:\Folder1)`, at some point `f.listFiles()` returns `null`. From the documentation, listFiles

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

Clearly, the path denotes a directory. This probably means an I/O error occurs. But what is the error itself?

Comment: That's probably a path-too-long error.

Comment: If folder2 links to folder1 don't you get a directory loop?

Comment: Your question is obviously operating system specific (but you seems to care only about Windows). On Linux and Posix systems, you might get the `ELOOP` error code given by some syscall, see [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

Comment: @Cruncher, yes, as I stated in the question itself.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the native source code for Win32FileSystem [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/2a0c219cf228/src/windows/native/java/io/Win32FileSystem_md.c). It's JDK6, but just for kicks. the `Java_java_io_Win32FileSystem_list` is what you are looking for, but again the errors must be hidden with method calls. Go down the rabbit whole. I don't know `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, if you make this change

```
if(subs == null) 
{
    System.out.println("is now null");
    File h = new File(f,"t");
    h.createNewFile();
    return; // returns null at some point
}
```

to try and create a file at the top of the stack, you get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system
       at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
       .....
```

Also if you just add a check for if it is a directory

```
if(!f.isDirectory())
    System.out.println("######## Not a Directory  #####");
```

at the point at the top of the stack this will print, so therefore `listFiles()` returns null because it is not a directory, so no exception thrown, which would be due to OS and the path being to long.

Comment: Interesting indeed. I especially like the approach you took to check this.